# search for the lowest (at the deepest level) node in n-ary tree of the same label

Tags: java, arraylist, tree

**this is the node class for my n-ary tree**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Node{
    public String label;
    public ArrayList<Node> children;
    public Node(String label){
        this.label =label;
        this.children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }
    public void addChild(String child){
        Node childNode = new Node(child);
        this.children.add(childNode);
    }
    public void addChild(Node child){
        this.children.add(child);
    }
    public Node findNode(String label){
        if(this.label.equals(label))
            return this;
        for(Node child : this.children)
            if (child.findNode(label) != null)
                return child.findNode(label);
        return null;
    }
}
```

i need a method like "`Node findNode(String label)`" but gives the lowest possible Node with the same label.

Example in this image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after modifying [Siddarth Sreeni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474176/search-for-the-lowest-at-the-deepest-level-node-in-n-ary-tree-of-the-same-labe/59476262#59476262) some more i came up with this answer that seems to be the correct one

**here is the code :**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Node{
    public String label;
    public ArrayList<Node> children;
    private int level;
    public Node(String label){
        this.level =0;
        this.label =label;
        this.children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }

    public void addChild(String label){
        Node child = new Node(label);
        child.setLevel(this.getLevel()+1); //setting children level
        this.children.add(child);
    }
    public void addChild(Node child){
        child.setLevel(this.getLevel()+1); //setting children level
        this.children.add(child);
    }
    public Node findNode(String label){
        if(this.label.equals(label))
            return this;
        for(Node child : this.children)
            if (child.findNode(label) != null)
                return child.findNode(label);
        return null;
    }

    //note : This assumes you are at any Node searching for a child node. The root Node will have level = 0 ~important
    public Node findDeepNode(String label){
        Node tempNode = null;
        if(this.label.equals(label)&&this.findNode(label)==null){
            tempNode = this;
        }
        //traverse this' children
        for(Node child : this.children){
            Node t = child.findNode(label);
            if(t!=null){
                if(tempNode!=null){
                    if(tempNode.getLevel()<t.getLevel() && t.findDeepNode(label)==null){
                        tempNode=t;
                    }else tempNode=t.findDeepNode(label);
                }else{
                    if(t.findDeepNode(label)==null)
                        tempNode=t; //set TempNode = t as tempNode is null as this is our first solution
                    else tempNode=t.findDeepNode(label); //set TempNode = t.findDeepNode(label) as t has a child of the same label to put in tempNode instead
                }
            }
        }
        return tempNode; //can be null and Contains the lowest node in the tree with label
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Node node=new Node("E");
        node.addChild("E-");
        node.addChild("T-");
        node.addChild("7");
        node.findNode("E-").addChild("F");
        node.findNode("E-").addChild("T");
        node.findNode("T-").addChild("8");
        node.findNode("T-").addChild("9");
        node.findNode("9").addChild("9");
        node.findDeepNode("9").addChild("T");
        System.out.println(node.findDeepNode("T").level);
    }
}
```

**This image explains the main method used for testing :**

[image]

Comment: Which node is returned for 2 'T's at the same level? Which node is returned when a 'T' is the child of another 'T' (or further down that subtree)?

Comment: @rsp 1st-probably the one that you added first, for my use case this would not be a problem. 2nd-(when a 'T' is the child of another 'T' the child node is returned as it is the lowest)normally, but there is indeed an error

Comment: @rsp 2nd-when a 'T' is the child of another 'T' the child node is returned as it is the lowest (maybe fixed after the last edit)

Answer (score 1):

> Modify your `Node.class` to store another variable the `int height` which is derived whilst you traverse your `Tree objectTree` from the `rootNode`.

The rootNode.getHeight()=0 by default. Simple traversal from the `rootNode` function in `Node.class` will look like the following:

```
//note : This assumes you are at any Node. The root Node will have height = 0 ~important
public Node findLabel(String label){ 
   Node tempNode = null;
   assert this.getHeight()!=null;
   if(this.label.equals(label)){
     tempNode = this;
   }
   //traverse this' children 
   for(Node child : this.children){
         child.setHeight(this.getHeight()+1); //setting children height
         Node t = child.findNode(label);
         if(t!=null){
           if(tempNode!=null){ 
              if(tempNode.getHeight()>t.getHeight()){
                 tempNode=t;
              }
           }else{
             tempNode=t; //set TempNode = t as tempNode is null as this is our first solution
           }
         }      
    }
  return tempNode; //can be null and Contains the lowest node in the tree with label
}
```

Comment: better setheight in addchild method because in this code " t " will have a level == 0 so the comparison is useless

Comment: Thought of that, but considering how the usually one can never predict when the ```rootNode``` changes was un-predictable and even harder to all visualise it. The root node has to be set 0 and the rest iterates based on this. If i'm wrong, can you explain it?

Comment: i've made an answer you can see if it makes sense to you

Comment: @B15 haha sorry! i didnt see that until now. If i were to create 3 nodes and then (for simplicity a ```1--->2--->3```) I'd create ```3``` first and assign height 2. But then if i want to reformat. It feels like i'd have to modify the height manually!. Figured i can resolve it in iteration! But i just tried to make it simple! Hope it worked for u

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it's just an idea, i haven't tried it.
You need to count the number of odd nodes you have passed.

```
public static int max_depth = 0;
public static Node max_Node = null;
public Node findNode(String label){
   int counter = 0;
    if(this.label.equals(label))
        if(max_depth < counter){
            max_Node = this;
            max_depth = counter;
        }

    for(Node child : this.children){
         if (child.findNode(label) != null){
              if (child.findNode(label) != null){
                  counter++;
                   Node findNode(String label);
              }
         }

    }
  }
```

Comment: quite confusing to be honest. so what does " Node findDeepNode(String label); " refer to and where is the return statement ?

Comment: you don't need to modify the method " findNode(String label) " it has a purpose to serve making an other method  like " Node findDeepNode(String label); " would be better ?